# Java Logging - Debug Level log not appeared in the eclipse console

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, logging

For debugging my application, trying to display debug level logs in the eclipse console with the below configuration. But only INFO, ERROR and FATAL are displayed, but not the DEBUG level logs.

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=D:/log/oms-web.log
#log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
#log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern= %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the date/time, calling class and message.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %C.%M(): %m%n

# Root logger option
log4j.rootCategory=INFO ,file,stdout,DEBUG
log4j.category.org.springframework.beans.factory=OFF
# Log everything. Good for troubleshooting
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=OFF

# Log all JDBC parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=OFF
log4j.logger.org.springframework=OFF
```

Please help me to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Change the rootCategory to:

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG ,file,stdout
```